# Where and clause in codeigniter for voting system

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am implementing a voting system in codeigniter: The problem is that everytime a user clicks on upvote  `$this->db->set('up', 'up+1', FALSE);` is executed and up is incremented by one. But it should only increment if `count == 0`.

My Model code is :

```
public function up_votes($id,$ip) {  

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM voting_ip WHERE open_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip';");  

    $result = $query->row_array();
    $count = $result['COUNT(*)'];

    if($count == 0) {
        $this->db->set('up', 'up+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('open_id', $id);
        $this->db->update('country');
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a `;` in your sql that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of count you use `$query->num_rows()`

**MODEL**

```
public function up_votes($id,$ip) {  
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM voting_ip WHERE open_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");  
   $count= $query->num_rows();
    if($count == 0) {
        $this->db->set('up', 'up+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('open_id', $id);
        $this->db->update('country');
        return TRUE;
    }else{
         return FALSE;
     }

}
```

Comment: the error is in  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM voting_ip WHERE open_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");  
   $count= $query->num_rows(); these two lines

Comment: no error but a success message is displayed...You have Upvoted This Letter Successfully Thank you ! Back to Letter!

Comment: may be problem is with you condition of controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the `COUNT` also -

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM voting_ip WHERE open_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change below line

> $count = $result['COUNT(*)'];

With

> $count = sizeof($result);

Beacuse in CI, `row_array` function returns array, so you can count the size of array. Check this link : [Generating Query Results](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)